# VBA Userform data entry replaces row rather than adds to row underneath?

Tags: excel, vba

I am seeking to implement a userform that adds data to a list. The userform accurately inputs the data into the correct columns. I would like to add data, and then move onto the next row where I can input another line of data. However, when I click the command button for the 2nd set, it replaces the same line rather than moving to the one underneath. I have my code attached, i believe it is something wrong with the "iRow" equation. I am new to VBA, and could use some help. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub cmd_add_Click()    
    Dim iRow As Long    
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Program Detail Input")

    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=” * ”, SearchOrder:=xlRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    iRow = iRow + 1

    If Trim(Me.txtprgrm) = "" Then    
        MsgBox "Please enter a Program Name"    
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Trim(Me.cboRegion) = "" Then    
        MsgBox "Please enter a region"   
        Exit Sub   
    End If

    With ws 
        ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtprgrm.Value    
        ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.cboRegion.Value    
        ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.cboStatus.Value    
        ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    End With

    Me.txtprgrm.Value = ""    
    Me.cboRegion.Value = ""    
    Me.cboStatus.Value = ""    
    Me.txtprgrm.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Right after your first iRow assignment place: msgBox iRow or use the immediate window, you will know if the way your are selecting the last row is working or not.

Comment: Please note that these fancy quotes `” * ”` are not allowed in VBA and must be replaced by the simple ones `" * "`. Otherwise it won't work.